Microsoft Game Publish Dependencies Unity UWP
Where do i put Dependencies while publishing on Microsoft Partner Center? I'm trying to publish a game for Xbox, but they dont accept the dependencies files only the appxupload.
Dindt find anything about it on the internet.

When user install your app from the Store, if your dependencies are available in the Store as well, the store will automatically install the dependencies from the store.
Or your package needs to contain all the necessary dependencies inside it.
